# Android google map marker icon loss it's quality of original image

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I think my problem looks like similar with this question:
[Google maps marker icons - loss in image quality when resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310653/google-maps-marker-icons-loss-in-image-quality-when-resizing)

This is original image file that used icon of marker.
[image]

This is how marker's icon look like:
[image]

There is any solutions to preserve original image size?

- Sorry for my bad english :/

Answer (score 0):

Android resize images by itself to fit the android standard. I advise you to resize your icon by yourself to 256*256 which is tha maximum size of an android icon so you won't lose on quality

Comment: Unfortunately, 256x256 image showing too large and also image losing it's quality. I tried to use SVG vector(xml) to marker but it does not applied to BitmapDescriptor

Comment: Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(x, y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getResources().getIdentifier("custom_icon"), null, new RectF(0, 0, x, y), color);
            MarkH = new MarkerOptions().position(Position).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp));

Comment: I tried your code but it does not worked for me :S ty for your comment